# django inability to find blog url while rendering the html page

Tags: python, django

I am newbie to django. I am trying to develop blog app in django.
I trying to render my fetched data into html but unable to do it for the following code
for which it is printing no blog found even data is being fetched properly.

This is my **views.py**

```
def blogpost(request):

    latest_blog_list = BlogPost.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    print "" + str(latest_blog_list)
    context = {'latest_poll_list' : latest_blog_list}
    print "" + str(context)

    #I can see the data is being fetched properly
    return render(request,'polls/blogPostlist.html',context)
```

my **blogPostlist.html**

```
    {% if latest_blog_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for blogpost in latest_blog_list %}
        <li> <a href="/blog/{{ blogpost.slug }}"> blogpost.title </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% else %}
           <p> test No blog avilable</p>
    {% endif %}
```

**models.py**

```
    class BlogPost(models.Model):
        title       = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        post        = models.TextField()
        #media_file = models.ImageField(upload="")
        pub_date    = models.DateTimeField()
        visit_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        slug        = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=255)
        published   = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        tag         = models.ManyToManyField(BlogTag)
        catagory    = models.ManyToManyField(BlogCategory)


        def __unicode__(self):
            return u'%s' % self.slug

        class Meta:
            ordering = ["pub_date"]
```

Along with that if I want to get title and slug for the blog, how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The context key name is wrong:

```
context = {'latest_poll_list' : latest_blog_list}
```

Instead it should be:

```
context = {'latest_blog_list' : latest_blog_list}
```